# Why does fscanf ignore the first string?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a translator.
 This is the part where I put all the strings from the text file on the memory.
 But the program ignores the first string of the text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct b
{
   char b[30];
}b;
int main()
{
    int d,c,i=0;
    char k[30],x;
    b *a;
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp=fopen("translate.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
       printf("Σφάλμα κατά το άνοιγμα του αρχείου\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s",k);
            i++;
        }
        a=malloc((i)*(sizeof(b)));
        fclose(fp);
    }
    if ((fp=fopen("translate.txt","r+"))==NULL)
    {
       printf("Σφάλμα κατά το άνοιγμα του αρχείου\n");
    }
    else
    {
        rewind(fp);
        for (c=0;c<i;c++)
       {
        fscanf(fp,"%s",a[c].b);
       }
       fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? You read the string to the buffer `k` and read the next string. Which will over write the first read string

Comment: @Gopi The first fscanf is used to count the number of words on the text file.

Comment: What was confirmed doing "ignores the first string of the text file"?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am trying to make a translator.Firstly I load the content of the text file to the memory, make changes(add-delete-edit words) and then
load them again to the text file.But when I load them, the first word is missing

Comment: In your code shown of it does not exist part that you can check it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The total code is over 500 lines so I didn't put all of it here.

Comment: There is no reason why the first word is ignored by this code. It did not reproduce.

Comment: try `fscanf(fp,"%29s",k);` and `fscanf(fp,"%29s",a[c].b);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That works as ameyCU answered but I don't know why.

Comment: Perhaps, what is happening is a buffer overrun exists 30 or more characters of the word in translate.txt. I think so that there is a need to change the size of the buffer to the appropriate size.

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for a discussion of why you should not use the loop you show.

Comment: Yes, from where did you get '30'?  Why not, say, 256'?

Comment: when writing code, always use meaningful names.  names like d, c, i, k, x, a are not meaningful.   In general, a variable name should either express its' usage or its' content.

Comment: the `typedef` can be understood by a modern compiler, but for us humans, the tag name, the field name, and the typedef name being all the same leads to confusion.   Suggest using meaningful, unique names

Comment: when a call to `fopen()` fails, it is much better to call `perror()` as that will (on stderr) output both the enclosed text and the message from the OS as to why it thinks the call to `fopen()` failed.

Comment: regarding this line: `fscanf(fp,"%s",k);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful  2) the '%s' input/conversion specifier was not given a limit, to the input buffer `k[]`  can be easily overrun, resulting in undefined behaviour.  Suggest: (remembering that scanf() with a '%s' will always append a NUL byte) `if( 1 != fscanf(fp,"%29s",k) ) { handle error }

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=c99` ),  The posted code causes the complier to output a long string of error/warning messages.   These messages indicate problems in the code that need to be fixed.

Comment: the call to `malloc()` causes the compiler to raise a warning about the implicit conversion from int to unsigned long.  Suggest: `a=malloc( (size_t)i * sizeof(b) );`

Comment: the system function: `rewind()` is really designed for tape drives,   For disk files, a much better function is: `fseek()`.  Why call `rewind()`?  the file was just opened, so the 'file pointer' will be at the beginning of the file.

Comment: for readability and ease of understanding by us humans, please consistently indent the code.

Comment: the overall code can be greatly simplified by 1) calling `realloc()` to expand an initial size for the memory allocation pointed to by `a`.  2) using `fgets()` to read each line from the file, then replacing the newline chars with a NUL byte.  The call to `fgets()` can easily be used for loop control.

Comment: if the first call to `fopen()` fails, but the second call succeeds, then the loop after the second call will: 1) be using an uninitialized memory pointer `a` 2) be using an uninitialized local variable `c`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. I.E 30.   'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest: using a #define to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You should write this loop (*so as to check return of* `fscanf` ) —

```
  for (c=0;c<i;c++)
  {
    fscanf(fp,"%s",a[c].b);
  }
```

as —

```
c=0;
while (fscanf(fp,"%29s",a[c].b) == 1 && c<i){
 ...
 c++;
}
```

**2.** Also `while(!feof(fp))` is wrong, so instead use `fscanf` to control the loop —

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%29s",k)==1)
  i++;
```

**Note** — And, just to avoid confusion, give different names to your structure member and structure.

Answer (score 0):

after applying all the comments, the resulting code is:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main( void )
{
    char **lines = NULL;
    size_t lineCount = 0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if ((fp=fopen("translate.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
       perror("Σφάλμα κατά το άνοιγμα του αρχείου\n");
       exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    char * inputBuf = NULL;
    size_t inputLen = 0;

    while( getline( &inputBuf, &inputLen, fp ) )
    {
        lineCount++;
        char **tempLines = realloc( lines, (lineCount+1)*sizeof( char*) );
        if( !tempLines )
        { // then realloc failed
            perror( "realloc failed");
            free( lines );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        lines = tempLines;
        lines[lineCount] = strdup( inputBuf );
        lineCount++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free( lines );
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

however, this code is not very efficient as it repeatedly calls `realloc()`

To fix that, initially allocate enough room in `lines[]` for several lines, say 10, then keep a count of how many of those pointers are being used.

When all the allocated pointers are used and need to add another line, then double the allocation via `realloc()`.